# How to set display ICC profile in Kubuntu?

Tags: kde, colors, icc

How to set ICC profile for display in Kubuntu? In System Settings - Color I can add .icc file to the device, set the checkbox. But the device does not actually use the profile. There is no apply button or something, too.No errors when run from the terminal, too. Just don't work.

Comment: Not really an answer, but you can do it via cli with `dispwin -d 1 -I /path/to/profile.icc`. Or use `dispcalgui`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found Nvidia blob guilty of ignoring ICC. After switching to nouveau all started working.

Comment: Somebody just upvoted this answer, so I have to say: these days it all work normally with Nvidia blob.

Answer (score 7):

For me in Kubuntu 18.04/bionic the following worked:

Install *colord-kde*
This adds a page in the system settings devices section. There, in the *profiles* tab, I could install my icc profile system-wide (to */var/lib/colord/icc/*).

Run `colormgr get-devices-by-kind display` and lookup the id of your display.

Run `colormgr find-profile-by-filename /var/lib/colord/icc/<name of your icc file>` to lookup the id of your profile.

Then run the following commands to connect the profile to your display and make it default:

```
colormgr device-add-profile <display id> <profile id>
colormgr device-make-profile-default <display id> <profile id>
```