# How do I change color profile via terminal commands?

Tags: command-line, color-management

I frequently change color profiles from the color settings. I would like to set an alias for convenient switching between color profiles e.g. D50 to D55 and switch back.

[image]

Does anyone know how to change via terminal commands?

In reply to A.B. answer :

```
$ colormgr get-devices
Object Path:   /org/freedesktop/ColorManager/devices/xrandr_Apple_Computer_Inc_Color_LCD_evn_1000
Owner:         evn
Created:       May  7 2015, 03:36:44 PM
Modified:      May  9 2015, 08:48:18 AM
Type:          display
Enabled:       Yes
Embedded:      Yes
Model:         MacBookAir4,2
Vendor:        Apple
Serial:        unknown
Seat:          seat0
Scope:         temp
Colorspace:    rgb
Device ID:     xrandr-Apple Computer Inc-Color LCD
Profile 1:     icc-df7c0067b1eb9bcc9fc9b33bc3a797eb
               /usr/share/color/icc/colord/Gamma5000K.icc
Profile 2:     icc-57f0d896250f6f98f77ca1b0d19019c0
               /usr/share/color/icc/colord/Gamma5500K.icc
Profile 3:     icc-c385a6cc9b355dfa77d994ff54626f8a
               /home/evn/.local/share/icc/edid-2fa49b462ac314062ce76fce977d6525.icc
Metadata:      XRANDR_name=eDP1
Metadata:      OutputPriority=primary
Metadata:      OwnerCmdline=/usr/lib/unity-settings-daemon/unity-settings-daemon 
Metadata:      OutputEdidMd5=2fa49b462ac314062ce76fce977d6525

$ colormgr device-get-default-profile xrandr-Apple Computer Inc-Color LCD
Not a valid object path: xrandr-Apple
$ colormgr device-get-default-profile xrandr_Apple_Computer_Inc_Color_LCD_evn_1000
Not a valid object path: xrandr_Apple_Computer_Inc_Color_LCD_evn_1000
```

I am getting an error that "Not a valid object path: ...".  A.B. do you know how to resolve this erorr?

A.B. answered: double quotes for the ID.

```
$ colormgr device-get-default-profile "xrandr-Apple Computer Inc-Color LCD"
Not a valid object path: xrandr-Apple Computer Inc-Color LCD

$ colormgr device-get-default-profile "xrandr_Apple_Computer_Inc_Color_LCD_evn_1000"
Not a valid object path: xrandr_Apple_Computer_Inc_Color_LCD_evn_1000
```

Pasted full path worked.  Thanks A.B.!

```
$ colormgr device-get-default-profile /org/freedesktop/ColorManager/devices/xrandr_Apple_Computer_Inc_Color_LCD_evn_1000
Object Path:   /org/freedesktop/ColorManager/profiles/icc_df7c0067b1eb9bcc9fc9b33bc3a797eb
Owner:         root
Format:        ColorSpace..
Title:         D50
Qualifier:     RGB..
Type:          display-device
Colorspace:    rgb
Gamma Table:   Yes
System Wide:   Yes
Filename:      /usr/share/color/icc/colord/Gamma5000K.icc
Profile ID:    icc-df7c0067b1eb9bcc9fc9b33bc3a797eb
Metadata:      CMF_version=1.0.6
Metadata:      CMF_product=colord
Metadata:      FILE_checksum=df7c0067b1eb9bcc9fc9b33bc3a797eb
Metadata:      CMF_binary=cd-create-profile
Metadata:      License=CC0
Metadata:      DATA_source=test
```

Comment: I'm just not at the PC. Please try double quotes for the id.

Comment: In case one starts with a file, complete solution: https://askubuntu.com/questions/199661/how-do-you-set-system-display-color-profiles-in-xubuntu-and-lubuntu

Answer (score 6, accepted):

from `man colormgr`

```
[..]

DESCRIPTION
       This manual page documents briefly the colormgr command.

       colormgr allows an administrator to view and change color profile to device mappings.

[..]
```

List all devices, eg:

```
$ colormgr get-devices 
Object Path:   /org/freedesktop/ColorManager/devices/cups_HP_Color_LaserJet_CP1514n
Owner:         root
Created:       Mai  9 2015, 07:57:21 
Modified:      Mai  9 2015, 07:57:21 
Type:          printer
Enabled:       Yes
Embedded:      No
Model:         HP Color LaserJet cp1514n
Vendor:        Hewlett Packard
Serial:        socket://192.168.2.160
Format:        ColorModel.MediaType.Resolution
Scope:         temp
Colorspace:    rgb
Device ID:     cups-HP_Color_LaserJet_CP1514n
Profile 1:     HP_Color_LaserJet_CP1514n-RGB..
Profile 2:     HP_Color_LaserJet_CP1514n-Gray..
Metadata:      OwnerCmdline=/usr/sbin/cupsd -l
```

and get a profile with

```
$ colormgr device-get-default-profile cups-HP_Color_LaserJet_CP1514n
Object Path:   /org/freedesktop/ColorManager/profiles/HP_Color_LaserJet_CP1514n_RGB__
Owner:         root
Format:        ColorModel.MediaType.Resolution
Qualifier:     RGB..
Colorspace:    rgb
Scope:         temp
Gamma Table:   No
System Wide:   No
Profile ID:    HP_Color_LaserJet_CP1514n-RGB..
```

set a profile with:

```
colormgr device-make-profile-default cups-HP_Color_LaserJet_CP1514n /org/freedesktop/ColorManager/profiles/HP_Color_LaserJet_CP1514n_Gray__
```

check with:

```
$ colormgr device-get-default-profile cups-HP_Color_LaserJet_CP1514n                                                                        
Object Path:   /org/freedesktop/ColorManager/profiles/HP_Color_LaserJet_CP1514n_Gray__
Owner:         root
Format:        ColorModel.MediaType.Resolution
Qualifier:     Gray..
Colorspace:    gray
Scope:         temp
Gamma Table:   No
System Wide:   No
Profile ID:    HP_Color_LaserJet_CP1514n-Gray..
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution.  I tried to apply your solution for my situation.  However I'm getting an error while getting profile.  I pasted the details in my question above.  Would you please attend it?

Comment: It took a lot of hassle to get this working on 14.04. You have to use the full object paths of each the device and profile. You can get a profile path by running `colormgr get-devices`, copying the filepath of the profile (e.g. `/usr/share/color/icc/colord/Gamma6500K.icc`), then running `colormgr find-profile-by-filename /usr/share/color/icc/colord/Gamma6500K.icc`.

Comment: To load profile from file see https://askubuntu.com/questions/481297/how-to-set-display-icc-profile-in-kubuntu