# How can I reset the Cinnamon Desktop to its default colour scheme?

Tags: themes, colors, cinnamon, 22.10

Shortly after upgrading to Ubuntu 22.10 with Cinnamon Desktop, I somehow inadvertently ended up with a rather tacky blue-green tinted colour theme, which I have been unable to change.  The tint is also being applied to images and videos within applications, which makes it unacceptable for image editing.

[image: Screenshot showing theme with tinted B&W image]
Screenshot showing theme with some blue-green tinting evident in a B&W image. Even the Desktop background is "bluer" than it should be.

So far I have tried using "System Settings>Appearance>Themes"; "Panel>Troubleshoot>Restore all settings to default", and the following commands:

```
gsettings reset org.cinnamon.desktop.wm.preferences theme
gsettings reset org.cinnamon.desktop.interface gtk-theme
gsettings reset org.cinnamon.theme name
gsettings reset org.cinnamon.desktop.interface icon-theme
gsettings reset org.cinnamon.desktop.interface cursor-theme
```

and restarted, all without any effect.

I logged into the GNOME DE (which is still installed on this computer) twice, on Wayland and X11 respectively, and found the same colour theme is now present there, and again I could not find any option to remove it.

Advice would be appreciated - Cheers, Alan

Comment: Maybe cable or monitor settings? Cinnamon won't mess up its color-profile **and** that of Gnome. Btw -I don't see that "blue-green" tinting on your image - so check if it is hardware  related.

Comment: Thanks kanehekili,  yes viewing the above screenshot on another computer with almost identical installation and settings reveals a neutral colour theme.  I tested the problem PC with a different cable & monitor and the problem is still there, so the problem is occurring upstream of the PC's HDMI socket.   One thing I forgot to mention yesterday is the problem occurs ONLY WHILE LOGGED IN, i.e., the image which is used for both the desktop background and the login screen background reverts to its neutral tone when logged out.  To me this tends to rule out a hardware problem.

Comment: Sounds reasonable. Could it be the [colorManager](https://askubuntu.com/questions/621433/how-do-i-change-color-profile-via-terminal-commands)?

Comment: Thanks again @kanehekili, problem solved!  An old colour profile from a couple of years ago when I was fooling around with a Huey Pro (I had deselected that profile but not removed it), must have become reactivated somehow.  The offending profile has now been removed.  Cheers, Alan